# Use a third-party font in LaTeX (not XeLaTeX)

Tags: fonts, pdftex

Perhaps the question will sound a little concrete, not abstract, as it seems to me, it has a chance not to be deleted.

Suppose we have a set font styles of font: `regular.otf`, `italic.otf`, `bold.otf` and `bold_italic.otf`.
How to do so that would be typed in LaTeX (more specifically, pdfLaTeX) the text was made up of this font? Moreover, how to transfer this font into math mode, that is, to transfer into formulas the letters `a`-`z`, `A`-`Z` (probably here we are talking separately about symbols for plain text and symbols for mathematical operators) and symbols `.`, `,`, `:`, `;` `(`, `)`, `[`, `]` and etc., brackets `{`, `}` and some special characters given by commands, e. g., `\ell`.

The question is about using (pdf)LaTeX, not XeLaTeX.

UPD: I'm aware of the need to use the `otftotfm` utility, but I'm not sure how to use it for anything other than LY1 encoding, e. g., for the encodings OT1, OML, OMS, etc.

Comment: You need XeLaTeX or LuaLaTEX if you want to use OpenType fonts. Alternatively try to convert the font: https://www.lcdf.org/type/otftotfm.1.html

Comment: See also [How to install OTF fonts with otfinst.py?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/24691)

Comment: autoinst one of a better conversion tool to use OTF fonts in LaTeX